# Ionic Cordova discovered plugin every build

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am using ionic cordova to generate android/ios app, and when i run `ionic cordova run android` or `prepare android`, every time i have this log:

```
>cordova run android
Android Studio project detected
Discovered plugin "mx.ferreyra.callnumber" in config.xml. Adding it to the project
```

during 5 minutes!

why `cordova` do it at each time?

```
ionic-version : 4.1.2
cordova : 8.1.1
```

under windows 7

thanks

Comment: I had the same problem with another plugin. The problem was because the plugin had dependencies that were not satisfied and therefore it was not installed correctly. You should check that

Comment: ok i will try to see that, and another problem with ionic cordova run browser, i always have an error message with : Native: tried calling NativeStorage.setItem, but the NativeStorage plugin is not installed, but i have installed it! so i don't understant why i get this message, any idea?

Comment: That's because NativeStorage is for native devices, not browsers. Happens with the camera too. It's only installed for android in your case

Comment: no with chrome you have localstorage and i already see it working with browser, and now i have same problem with android studio and emulator, i have remove and add the nativestorage plugin but no effect.. i will try other answers. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using the gradle 'dependencies' task and the more detailed 'dependencyInsight' task has helped me a lot in the past with figuring out cordova dependency problems in the past. More info here [gradle dependency tasks](https://guides.gradle.org/building-android-apps/#run_standard_gradle_tasks)

Also, can you post your config.xml?

Answer (score 0):

Just as a suggestion, anytime you got a problem with plugins, first of all, I suggest you recreate the android platform.

```
 ionic cordova platform remove android
```

then remove **platforms/android** directory, then

```
 ionic cordova platform add android
```

And last,

```
ionic cordova platform prepare android
```